# AWS IoT SDK - Exception while building AWSIotData and AWSIotClient

Tags: java, apache, exception, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am currently using the aws-iot-sdk for java (v1.11.380) and when I am building my AWSIotData and AWSIotClient and I have a hidden exception that I found in debug mode: `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V`

My code is the following:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(configuration.getAccessKeyID(), configuration.getSecretAccessKey()));
AWSIotData awsIotDataClient = AWSIotDataClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                    .build();
AWSIot awsIotClient = AWSIotClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                    .build();
```

It blocks indefinitely after the first build and it does the same thing if I switch them.

The issue seems to be in the `SdkTLSSocketFactory` class in the `com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl` package while executing the super() call in the constructor (`super(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);`)

I guess this might be due to an Apache http client version conflict with the one I already use in my program but I do not really know how I could solve that issue.

Could anyone help me with that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After some additional hours, I found the solution.
Here is my pom.xml:

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iot</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.380</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```